# Python Requests, Successful website log in but redirects me to log in page

Tags: python, web-scraping, authentication, python-requests, login-script

I am trying to scrape a website using Python's Requests Module
It's a website we can only access inside our company.
Every time I try to scrape the website using `get()`, it show's this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.13 (Red Hat) Server at tcfabcert Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

But when I insert the `auth=('user','pass')`, it get's a respone of `200` but it doesn't log me in and every time I try to log in using `post()` method **it just keeps redirecting me to the same Login Page**.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

payload = {'userID': 'user',
'password': 'mypass',
'userLocale': 'US CA',
'userBU': 'MB',
'servName': 'Certification',
'login': 'Login',
'rememberFlag': 'false',
'hiddenHost': 'cpc44743'}

cookie = {'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=AF1A7CC747492C3D4259B230A5F7635A.PKYCUbG8Dba7VqoxAzD4WA'}

header = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Content-Length':'138',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=AF1A7CC747492C3D4259B230A5F7635A.PKYCUbG8Dba7VqoxAzD4WA',
'Host':'tcfabcert',
'Origin':'http://tcfabcert',
'Referer':'http://tcfabcert/ws/ess/default.jsp',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as r:
    url = "http://tcfabcert/ws/ess/"
    res = r.get(url, auth=('user', 'password')).text
    res2 = r.post(url, auth=('user', 'password'), datas=payload, headers=header, allow_redirects=True)
```

Here is the code of the log in page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<meta name="GENERATOR"
        content="IBM WebSphere Page Designer V3.5.2 for Windows" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>Editorial System</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ws/ess/theme/Style2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var GB_ROOT_DIR = "/ws/ess/greybox/";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ws/ess/greybox/AJS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ws/ess/greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ws/ess/greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
    <link href="/ws/ess/greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script language="JavaScript1.2">
<!-- Hide from older browsers

// Original JavaScript code by Duncan Crombie: dcrombie at chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

 function getCookie(name) { // use: getCookie("name");
        var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
        var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
        return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}

var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);   // plus 28 days

function setCookie(name, value) {        // use: setCookie("name", value);
        document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

// Stop hiding -->


function dispHandle(obj) {
        if (obj.style.display == "none")
                obj.style.display = "";
        else
                obj.style.display = "none";
}

</script>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">
function rememberMe(cbox)
{
        userIDValue  = document.forms(0).userID.value;
        userPWDValue = document.forms(0).password.value;
        userLocale = document.forms(0).userLocale.value;
        userBU = document.forms(0).userBU.value;

        if (cbox.checked)
        {
                document.forms(0).rememberFlag.value = "true";
                setCookie("userID", userIDValue);
                setCookie("userPWD", userPWDValue);
                setCookie("userLocale", userLocale);
                setCookie("userBU", userBU);
        }
}

//function to reset the locale/bu
function setUserLocale(userLocale, userBU)
{
        setCookie("userBU", userBU);
    setCookie("userLocale", userLocale);
        document.forms(0).submit();
}
function submitForm() {
        userIDValue  = new String();
        userIDValue  = document.forms(0).userID.value;
        userPWDValue = document.forms(0).password.value;
        userLocale = document.forms(0).userLocale.value;
        userBU = document.forms(0).userBU.value;

        rFlag    = document.forms(0).rememberFlag.value;

        if (document.forms(0).password.value.length <1)
        {
                //alert("Please enter password");
                //alert("Please enter password");
        }
        else if (rFlag = "true")
        {
                setCookie("userID", userIDValue);
                setCookie("userPWD", userPWDValue);
                setCookie("userLocale", userLocale);
                setCookie("userBU", userBU);
        }
        document.forms(0).submit();
}

function _HpbJumpURL(url)
{
        if (url != '')
        {
                window.location = url;
        }
}

function checkBrowser(){

        var userID=getCookie("userID");
        var userPWD = getCookie("userPWD");
        var userLocale = getCookie("userLocale");
        var userBU = getCookie("userBU");
        if (userID != null && userPWD != null)
        {
                document.forms(0).userID.value = userID;
                document.forms(0).password.value = userPWD;
        }

        this.ver=navigator.appVersion
                    this.dom=document.getElementById?1:0
                    //Changes made by ANANDA5 for IE8 Migration
                                 //this.ie6=(this.ver.indexOf("MSIE 6")>-1 && this.dom)?1:0;
                                   this.ie8=(this.ver.indexOf("MSIE 8")>-1 && this.dom)?1:0;
                        //End

        var hName= window.location.host;
        var hPlatform = "";

        if (hName.indexOf("cert") != -1 )
        {
                hPlatform = "Certification";
        }
        else if (hName.indexOf("prod") != -1)
        {
                hPlatform = "Production";
        }
        else if (hName.indexOf("int") != -1)
        {
                hPlatform = "Development";
        }
        else if (hName.indexOf("lngcentral") != -1)
        {
                hPlatform = "Production";
        }
        else
        {
                hPlatform = "Development";
        }


        document.login.servName.value=hPlatform;
        return this
}

function addToFavorites()
{
        window.external.AddFavorite(window.url, "EdSched");
}

function showNew()
{
        var userBU = getCookie("userBU");
        if (userBU != null && userBU != "LNFR")
        {
                var newPage=getCookie("newPage3-17");
                if (newPage == null || newPage=="TRUE")
                {
                        whatsNew =GB_showFullScreen("What's new for this Release","../whatsnew.jsp");
                }
        }
}

</script>

</head>


<body onload="checkBrowser(); showNew();">
<form name="login" method="post" action="/ws/ess/default.jsp"><!-- Set the Default Locale -->

<br>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<table style='background: #dae0d2 url("images/bg.gif") repeat-x bottom; border: 1px thin'>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td align="center"><img src="/ws/ess/images/edsched.png" border="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align="center"><label class="TextLabel4">(Editorial Scheduling System)</label> <br>
                        <br>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align="center"><label class="TextLabel4">Enter the Login Details</label> <br>
                        </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</center>
<center>
<table style='background: #dae0d2 url("images/bg.gif") repeat-x bottom; border: 1px thin'>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>

                        <div id="userDetails">
                        <center>
                        <table>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr class="EbTopBar">
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="EbTopBar">
                                                <td align="right" width="100"><label class="TextLabel1">UserId :</label></td>
                                                <td width="110"><input type="text" name="userID" value=""
                                                        class="EbInputBg" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="EbTopBar">
                                                <td align="right" width="100"><label class="TextLabel1">Password :</label></td>
                                                <td width="110"><input type="password" name="password" value=""
                                                        class="EbInputBg" size="15" tabindex="2"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </center>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div style="display:" id="vanisher">
                        <center>
                        <table>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr class="EbTopBar">
                                                <td align="right" width="100"><label class="TextLabel1">Location</label></td>

                                                <td width="110"><select id="userLocale" name="userLocale"
                                                         class="ComboBox_ID12">
                                                        <OPTION value="US CA" >US CA</OPTION>
<OPTION value="FR" >FR</OPTION>
<OPTION value="AU" >AU</OPTION>
<OPTION value="SNG" >SNG</OPTION>
<OPTION value="LNC" >LNC</OPTION>

                                                </select></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr class="EbTopBar">
                                                <td align="right" width="100"><label class="TextLabel1">Business Unit</label></td>


                                                <td width="110"><select id="userBU" name="userBU"
                                                        class="ComboBox_ID12">
                                                        <OPTION value="LNC" >LNC</OPTION>
<OPTION value="COS" >COS</OPTION>
<OPTION value="MI" >MI</OPTION>
<OPTION value="MB" >MB</OPTION>
<OPTION value="MDC-SNG" >MDC-SNG</OPTION>
<OPTION value="LNFR" >LNFR</OPTION>

                                                </select></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr class="EbTopBar">
                                                <td/>
                                                <td align="left" width="100"><label class="TextLabel1">Correct business unit must be selected</label></td>
                                        </tr>

                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </center>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <!--
                <TR>
                        <TD CLASS="link"><A HREF="javascript:dispHandle(vanisher)">Choose
                        Language </A></TD>
                </TR>
                -->
                <tr>
                        <td>
                        <center>
                        <table>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td align="right" width="100"><label class="TextLabel1">Platform :</label></td>
                                                <td width="110"><input type="text" name="servName" value=""
                                                        class="EbReadOnly" size="15" tabindex="3" readonly></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                                <td align="right" width="100"></td>
                                                <!--
                                                <TD WIDTH="110"><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="rememberme" VALUE="N"
                                                        ONCLICK="rememberMe(this);"><LABEL CLASS="TextLabel1">Remember Me</LABEL></TD>
                                                        -->
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </center>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                        <center>
                        <table id="loginButtons">
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td width="80"></td>
                                                <td><input type="submit" name="login"
                                                        value='Login'
                                                        onclick="submitForm()" class="EbButton" /></td>
                                                <td><input type="reset" name="cancel"
                                                        value='Cancel' class="EbButton" /></td>
                                                        <td width="80"></td>

                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </center>
                        </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>



</table>
</center>
<input type="hidden" name="rememberFlag" value="false">
<center><a href="/ws/ess/frontpage/bugs.jsp">Login problems?</a><br>
</center>
<center>
<table border="1">
        <tbody align="center">
                <tr>
                        <td align="center"><a href="javascript:setUserLocale('US', 'MB');">English</a></td>
                        <td align="center"><a href="javascript:setUserLocale('FR', 'LNFR')";>Français</a></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

</center>
<input name="hiddenHost" type="hidden" value='cpc44743'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `auth` kwarg is only for basic http auth. It does not seek out a form in the html, populate it, and follow the form action url.

Comment: are you trying to access the endpoint which needs login? try only to pass the cookie with ur session stored but not the auth.

Comment: @Erik That sounds vague for me, I mean can you elaborate it more? sorry i'm no native english speaker, anyway I tried inspecting it via Chrome, here is it's formload.
payload = {'userID': 'user',
'password': 'mypass',
'userLocale': 'US CA',
'userBU': 'MB',
'servName': 'Certification',
'login': 'Login',
'rememberFlag': 'false',
'hiddenHost': 'cpc44743'}

Comment: @YY the log in website is this. 'http://tcfabcert/ws/ess/', everytime I use the get() function it has a 401 response, unless I use the basic auth which will eventually leads me to the right log in page. that's where I'm stuck in, I can't log in from there. I tried using the cookies, it says I need a browser that can support framesets. Which I don't even underrstand. sorry newbie here.

Comment: I am thinking you can try accessing end point post the login page? with either the auth or cookie passed into? meaning try to get the endpoint in browser after login and access with Requests.

Comment: @YY can you please elaborate it more? with some samples? that would be really helpful! TIA!